# Random number in launch file

Tags: ros, gazebo, spawn-model, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm using ROS Indigo with Gazebo to simulate a robot and I would like to spawn my robot at random positions in the world. I use launch files to start the whole simulation. In these launch files the spawning position is initially defined. Therefore I thought it would be best to create a random position in the launch file but since this is all xml, I doubt this is possible. Does anyone have any idea how I can somehow change the spawning position each run? Somehow run an external C++ program that passes a random number to the launch file?

Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/216303/random-number-in-launch-file/) by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2015-08-21

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could use a script to generate random ros parameters. Just include something like

```
<param name="robot_position" command="$(find some_package)/scripts/generate_random_position.py"/>
```

and the generate_random_position.py just returns a random position.

---

Originally posted by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) with karma: 3519 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [niall](https://answers.ros.org/users/22476/niall/) on 2015-08-24**:
Great Idea! That way I don't have to alter my normal launch procedure, just put this script before the spawn robot. Thanks FooBar!

**Comment by [Jason-Zhou1](https://answers.ros.org/users/40699/jason-zhou1/) on 2020-11-01**:
Hi @NEngelhard @niall, may I know what are the contents in the "generate_random_position.py" file? Is "robot_position" a 2d vector?

**Comment by [hyunoklee](https://answers.ros.org/users/35908/hyunoklee/) on 2022-01-05**:
reference the python script this link
https://campus-rover.gitbook.io/lab-notebook/faq/using-args-params-roslaunch

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One straightforward option is to start the launch file once, but use the gazebo_ros_pkgs service API to just move the model around as described in [the "Set Model State Example" here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_comm&cat=connect_ros). You could write a small Python node that calls this service with some random pose whenever you require it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1